# how to delete record whose pk is anothers fk in linq

Tags: linq-to-sql

My database having fields like

```
CId(PK- Auto Generated)
   IsSub(bit)
   PId(FK)
```

In this structure, Cid is auto generated and if new record is child record of cid the Issub=true, and Pid= id of Cid.

Now when i want to delete record that having no child elements it works perfect.
but if there is nested records then it will show me an error.

How can do deletion of that record having nested records.
     CID    IsSub   PID

```
  1         FALSE   null
  2         FALSE   null
  3         TRUE    2
  4         TRUE    2
```

In above how can i delete CID=2 ?

My Code is
v

```
ar del = context.DataTable.Where(c => c.CId == userData.CId).Single();
                context.DataTable.DeleteObject(del);
                context.SaveChanges();
```

This will delete single record that do not holding any reference key.
what can i do to delete both
1) delete cid=1

or to delete cid=2, will delete cid=3 and 4 also.

Answer (score 0):

Linq2SQL doesn't have an inherent cascading delete capability - you will need to do the work yourself. Some ideas [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386925.aspx) and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/CascadingDeletes_cs.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

When you create the fk you can specify whether it should delete child record automatically when the parent is deleted or raise an exception.
Your foreign key obviously raises an exception.

There are three possible solutions:

1. Change the foreign key so that it deletes the child record. (apparently, this feature is missing in your database)
2. Manually delete the child records before deleting the parent.
3. Set the parent of the child record to null (or to the parent of the parent) before deleting the parent.